how to solve error "spurious 8259A interrupt: IRQ7."?
I have this error in dmesg
"spurious 8259A interrupt: IRQ7."
I have tried those solutions
disable iommu by grub
disable iommu in bios
And simply don't work
Anyone knows more? thanks
system is
ASUSTeK Pro B550M-C
cpu is AMD Ryzen 3 3200G with Radeon Vega Graphics
ram 64gb
disk are serial ata in raid (zfs)
distro is Debian 12
kernel is 6.1.0-28-amd64
the system works fine nothing happen only I want to know if is possible to "solve" this message, anyway
EDIT1
cat /proc/interrupts report this
   5:          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC    5-edge      parport0
   7:          0          0          0          2  IR-IO-APIC    7-fasteoi   pinctrl_amd

and this line about the spurious interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts


What's the whole message? What are the surrounding messages? What's happening when you get this message?

The system works fine, but on other motherboards this message don't appear

Classically, the default usage of IRQ 7 is for the (essentially obsolete) parallel port (also known as IEEE 1284 or LPT)... and apparently your system includes a "LPT header" on the motherboard. Plugging in a ribbon cable with a suitable connector at the end would let you add a real parallel port to your system, if you happened to need one for some reason.
A single spurious interrupt is harmless. But if the count of spurious interrupts in /proc/interrupts keeps increasing, it might possibly have some small effect on system performance. (See grep SPU: /proc/interrupts)
If you are not using the parallel port, you might want to go to the BIOS settings and verify the parallel port is disabled.
Here is the BIOS manual for your motherboard series:
https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/Manual/PRIME_TUF_GAMING_B550_Series_BIOS_EM_WEB_EN.pdf
Unfortunately it is not specific to your exact model, and does not mention parallel port or LPT at all, since most motherboards in that series don't have a parallel port. But if there is a way to switch off the parallel port hardware, it would probably be in the Advanced Mode, in the Advanced -> Onboard Devices Configuration section.
If switching off the parallel port hardware does not help or is not possible, you might try loading the parport_pc kernel module if it isn't already loaded. It should be able to take control of the parallel port hardware, and automatically turn off its interrupts when the port is not in use.
It might not eliminate the message about the first spurious interrupt as it probably gets generated very early during the boot process, but it should stop the generation of further spurious interrupts from the parallel port hardware, and so eliminate any performance effects.
(I am guessing that the root cause is that the system firmware is leaving the parallel port interrupt enabled at boot time. A BIOS update could possibly fix this.)

Thanks for answer, I will upload more info now

Looks like on your system, the parallel port (parport0) is using IRQ 5, and IRQ 7 is taken by the pinctrl_amd module. But both IRQ lines have been successfully switched to using IR-IO-APIC, so the legacy 8259A interrupt controller should no longer be relevant with those IRQs at all once boot is complete and Linux has fully taken control of the hardware. What does the "Spurious interrupts" line in /proc/interrupts look like? If it has non-zero numbers, are the numbers growing over time?

SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts

Good, then it looks like IRQ 7 only emits about two spurious interrupts until the boot process transitions away from the legacy 8259A interrupt controllers to IO-APIC, and after the transition there seems to be no further spurious interrupts. That's quite harmless, but unfortunately I think only a BIOS update could make that "spurious 8259A interrupt: IRQ7" message go away.

Thanks for answer, I just updated the bios two days ago. But message persist. I think is a problem of asus motherboards on Linux
